# Head tag content misplaced

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9, head

I have an html document with the following structure:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
     <base href="http://www.mywebpage.com/subdir/"></base>
<title>home</title> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"></meta> 
     <link href="mystylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
Irrelevant content here
</body>
</html>
```

Now, the page looks fine when called directly, but when I use an include() call from another file in the same server, IE9 goes nuts. It disregards the base tag and the CSS styles. When I look at it with the content inspector, all the head content, except the title, is rendered as if they were inside the body section. Even the !Doctype. Also, the inspector shows empty text before and after the misplaced tags. I've checked my file for special, invisible charachters with notepad++ and I've found nothing.

The problem does not reproduce in Firefox. When I use Chrome, it shows the content as it should, but it does misplace the same tags as IE.

Comment: What does the raw source of the page look like? It sounds like you are just including the whole HTML page in the body of another page to me. I would certainly suspect you are generating some invalid markup which is why behaviour differs between browsers (since it is undefined and they are probably all doign their version of best guess). Possibly show us the code for the include that you are using. Is there any other markup being added aroudn the include?

Comment: Which “ include() call” are you referring to?

Comment: @Chris Yes, I'm tying to include a complete html document inside another file, but since the parent file has no html code at all it should be OK. I doubt there's something wrong with the markup, which you can see directly copied and pasted from notepad++ above, because all browsers parse it exactly as they should when I open the html file directly, not from inside the php file. If there was something wrong with the html code, there should be no difference between them.

Comment: @Jukka-k-korpela An include() function calling this file from a php file

Comment: You might want to reconsider using the base tag.  Browsers are fine with it, but I've had some really bad crawlers come through my site that completely ignored it and generated thousands of 404 requests.

Comment: @Variax: Is that actually the document your browser is getting or the one that you think it should be getting? As in if you do a view source in any of your browsers do you see the above? Alternatively is the page anywhere that we can see it for ourselves to try to work out what its doing or is it on a dev site?